# Terminal keystroke / combination to skip just the current passage in a shell script execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, debian, scripting

I often run bash scripts in debian and in general in linux.

We all know the CTRL + C key combination to break the current program and close the executable / script but this keystroke terminate the batch/script completely.

What I'm looking for instead is a keystroke **to just SKIP (like a nested CTRL +C) only for the very actual passage** even if not doing that passage would result in a buggy situation, like what "break" and "continue" do in a for cycle.

Example script:

**demo.sh**

```
wget http://something_from_the_internet...
unzip that_file
ping my_host
4th passage...
5th passage...
```

I would like to hit the combination to skip to the 2 command (in this case unzip), or hit twice and go directly to the 3rd command (in this case the ping...).

In many cases the result of a script file is given by all the passages.. but in my case not really, for testing purposes have a combination like that would allow me to run and test things without having the need of commenting all the lines on top just to fast check the latest on bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "skip" a running process with bash. According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Signals.html) page from bash docs, even if it had a skip behavior for a signal, it would wait until the process finished execution to issue the skip, effectively skipping only the following instruction. You can, though, change the way your script runs so that it kills the unzip process for you, if running on background, upon receiving a SIGINT for example ([guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_12.html)).

Comment: or one could simply make the script interactive with y/n questions if the next step should proceed or be skipped.

Comment: @hyph yes but the script I'm doing is meant to be completely unattended.. the annoying part is for the developing and testing.. insert "skip or not" questions is even more time consuming than commenting the actual code that I don't want to run in the first place :\

Comment: Why don't you put questions with a timeout? If nothing is pressed it goes unattended... I've never done this, but should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option of capturing the `SIGINT` signal using Bash's builtin `trap`:

`trap [COMMANDS] [SIGNALS]`

You can, for example, capture a `SIGINT` that was sent to the script in the foreground to send a signal to the process that was forked from the script.

In this case, however, you'll need the PID of the forked process. You can make use of Bash's `$!` variable, but it only works for processes that were forked to the background.

As a workaround, to preserve the synchronous nature of your script, you can explicitly call `wait` on the returned PID.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function skip() {
  kill -SIGTERM $!
}

trap skip SIGINT

ping ... &
wait $!

wget ... &
wait $!

unzip ... &
wait $!
```